# Monitor the current going into iPhone or iPad when charging

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uidevice

Is there a way to see the levels of current that are going into the iPhone or iPad when it is charging?

I know of some code that allows you to see the level at which the battery is charged but I'd like to be able to see the current that is going into the device when it is charging.
Does code like this exist?

All I've come across is:

```
float batteryLevel = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryLevel;
UIDeviceBatteryState currentState = [UIDevice currentDevice].batteryState;
```

However, these only tell you the level of the battery or if it's plugged in or not.

Comment: Five W pop up; why, why, why, why, why?

Comment: I have an idea for an app where this would be very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voltage does not *go into* the device and it's constant: It is always 5 volts (± 0.25 V, as defined by the USB standard).

It's the *current* that goes into the device and it's measured in amperes. The level of current defines how fast the battery is charging.

To my knowledge there's no public API to read any of these values.

Comment: Thanks I altered my question so it says current.

Comment: any private api to find amperes?